# SAPUI5 component ChartContainer property autoAdjustHeight not working

Tags: components, sapui5

I am using own component where I places ChartContainer in the flexbox (also was trying to use fixflex). The ChartContainer property autoAdjustHeight is not working correctly. In the chrome version 54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit) it did not stretch ChartContainer height till the end of the screen.

[image]

In the IE version 11.633.10586.0 this property behaves even stranger. The ChartContainer height is increasing few pixels per second and it did not stop (so it runs out of the screen and continue to increase its height).

In the Fiori Design Guidelines is written: The property autoAdjustHeight = true only works correctly if the page property enableScrolling is set to false. I set it exactly as it is recommended. Did anybode has similar problems as I am having with autoAdjustHeight property, when using it in the component? If yes I would be glad to not be alone.

When I use autoAdjustHeight in the xml code without component it works as it should. The problem is just when I am trying to implement it in my own component.

Here are some pieces of the code. This is page where component is loaded:

```
<core:View controllerName="abc.controller.Test"
           xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
           xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
           xmlns="sap.m" 
           xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
           xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout">  

    <Page id="idSCVerticalLayout" title="ABC" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="onNavBack" enableScrolling="false">

    </Page>
 </core:View>
```

And this is component xml which is placed inside the page (result is shown in the picture):

```
<mvc:View controllerName="root.hm.bas.analysis.ABC.controller.ABC"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:suite="sap.suite.ui.commons" 
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" 
    xmlns:viz="sap.viz.ui5.controls"        
        xmlns:common="sap.ui.commons">
        <FlexBox alignItems="Start" height="100%" >
            <items>                     
                <suite:ChartContainer
                    id="idChartContainer"
                    showFullScreen="false"
                    showPersonalization="false"
                    autoAdjustHeight="true"
                    showLegendButton="false"
                    showLegend="true"                       
                    showZoom="false"
                    title="">  

                    <suite:ChartContainerContent
                                icon = "sap-icon://bar-chart" 
                                title = "{i18n>chart}">     
                                <suite:content> 
                                    <viz:VizFrame id="categoryChart" uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}"></viz:VizFrame>
                                </suite:content>
                    </suite:ChartContainerContent>              

                </suite:ChartContainer> 
            </items>    
        </FlexBox>
</mvc:View>
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this question.
It seems like you are not alone.

I tried a demo example in

```
`https://plnkr.co/edit/XUC8nmAWiSJtHiycow7j?p=preview` :
```

With Chrome, the option “autoAdjustHeight” does not show any effect.
Both in IE and Firefox the bottom of the screen is sinking downwards as described by you.

We will look into this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the demo. I am looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Please have a look at https://plnkr.co/edit/PPCKs6jgJxpCHjrdq0Gw?p=preview .

In line 138 you can switch ‘AutoAdjustHeight’ from ‘true’ to ‘false’ and vice versa, to see the effect.

Comment: Thanks for this demo, but I also have this solution and it works correctly. The problem is when one tries to implement ‘AutoAdjustHeight’ property in the component as I asked at the beginning of this question. I would like to implement this property in the component demo which you sent before (https://plnkr.co/edit/XUC8nmAWiSJtHiycow7j?p=preview). Can you try it there?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with flex box, just remove the height of the flex box.

```
<FlexBox alignItems="Start" height="100%">
```

Remove height in this part and see.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I already tried it before I asked this question. It would be probably some bug.